# Experiences with logfaces

Tags: logging, aggregation

Someone at my company stumbled upon [logfaces](http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/features/index.php).  Does anyone have any experience with the product?  Any input would be helpful.  Basically we want a centralized place to check out our logs for multiple applications.  Needs to support .net and Java at a minimum.  Other products would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have been using LogFaces extensively for a year or so, and are very satisfied. It is lightweight and cheap, very sleek and robust, and has a complete range of filtering, reporting, alerting and sensible APIs where we can connect our own listeners. The product is actively developed, and the developer quickly responds to requests.

You've probably moved on, but I figured LogFaces needed a defender here. As for TheObjectGuy's Logverse I can't see that it supports anything but .Net, whereas LogFaces supports java, .Net, PHP and C++ through [Apache Logging Services](http://logging.apache.org/)

Comment: Logverse is completely agnostic with regard to the client. It supports .NET, Java, PHP, C++, etc.

Comment: Ok, nice to know. Sorry for the misinformation. Still happily using LogFaces though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Logverse](http://www.logverse.com).